# Disabling auto-matching of two or more lines by their max values

Tags: php, amcharts, multiple-axes

I am using [amchart](http://www.amcharts.com/) (not stock chart) to generate charts of two or more datasets. I noticed that lines with different values are being adjusted by their max values. Please have a look at the attached screenshot:

[image: amchart]

As you can see for example the amount 1.8k is above the amount 4.2k because of the enabled auto-adjustment. Searching through the amcharts forum gave no result. Thanks you in advance!

**UPDATE 1:**
I have found [one post with the similar problem](http://www.amcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=20505), but I think it is quite not a good way 
to adjust axises in such manner:

**UPDATE 2:**
Taking into consideration the @zerion's answer I have written some lines in my backend to be sure the synchronization will always be correct. I calculate min and max values for each numeral field that will be used as an axis, then using usort I sort the dataset array by (max - min) condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, or you can even tell the axis to synchronize:

valueAxis2.synchronizeWithAxis(valueAxis1);
valueAxis2.synchronizationMultiplier = 1;

So you should only think of which of your axis has the widest range of values, and sync other axes to this one.

Comment: For some incomprehensible reasons this method doesn't work when there are more than two axises, synchronization works only for the last axis, all others disappears:     `valueAxis1.synchronizationMultiplier = 1;  
valueAxis1.synchronizeWithAxis(valueAxis0);

valueAxis2.synchronizationMultiplier = 1;
    valueAxis2.synchronizeWithAxis(valueAxis0);  

    valueAxis3.synchronizationMultiplier = 1;  
    valueAxis3.synchronizeWithAxis(valueAxis0);`

Comment: It worked after I set synchronization as below: `...valueAxis1.synchronizationMultiplier = 1; valueAxis1.synchronizeWithAxis(valueAxis0); valueAxis2.synchronizationMultiplier = 1; valueAxis2.synchronizeWithAxis(valueAxis1); valueAxis3.synchronizationMultiplier = 1; valueAxis3.synchronizeWithAxis(valueAxis2);`
Thank you @zeroin!

Answer (score 2):

After more careful investigations I have found that the needed effect could be achieved by setting valueAxis.maximum (and maybe valueAxis.minimum if there are negative values) to the highest (lowest) value among all dataSets.